# Undefined Control Sequence ...entrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{33}}}

Tags: errors, glossaries

I recently switched from MikTex to TexLive.
At first, the document I had begun with miktex build just fine.
But now I'm getting the error below:

> File: Document.gls
>
> Type: error
>
> line 15: \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{33}}}\glsgroupskip
>
> Undefined control sequence ...entrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{33}}}

It seems to be some trouble with a glossary entry. Unfortunately, I have not been able to reproduce the error in a test-document.
Does anybody have an idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Try deleting the `.gls` file and rebuild your document.

Comment: Hm ... I deleted everything but the .tex and the .toc file and rebuilt the document. No errors on the first run. However, the glossary was of course not yet added to the document. So I hit the build button a second time and ... same issue as before.

Comment: In which case you need to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I HAVE told you that I cannot seem to reproduce the error. It MAY be related to the command defined by "\newcommand{\jap}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}#1\end{CJK}}", though. If I take them out, the errors *seem* to disappear. I can use the command just fine in any other document, though. AND copying head / foot of the document and stripping it of everything that is plain text does NOT reproduce the error.

Comment: @User1291 Well, sorry to say that, but explaining that you are unable to reproduce the error in a small document won't make the question answerable. The text `undefined control sequence` doesn't seem to show any specific control seqence, which is a bit strange. Could you please try to compile the document with adding `\tracingmacros=1` somewhere before where the error appears, then open the `.log` file and paste the error message from there, together with let's say 100 lines before it?

Comment: @User1291 What I meant was that without a MWE it's simply not possible to provide any further help.

Comment: I just had the same problem and traced it back to an _invalid command inside a glossary entry_. I got an error message as above in TeXstudio, but the actual log file contained two lines between "! Undefined control sequence." and "l.5 ...etentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{7}}}" with the actually undefined control sequence (and the offending glossary entry).

Comment: Same problem with error msg. The last comment describes exactly the place of the problem. Content of the two lines mentioned above was obviously CORRECT. BUT the babel pkg was not loaded, which handles \glqq. This command was the source of the error msg.